# How to make addSnapshotListener to not start a new activity? Works with Java but not Kotlin

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following code in the onCreate activity (tried with onStart, didn't work as well). Every time there is a change to any field in the document gameID, the activity starts again with the new data. Is it possible to just make it update the text field mPlayersLeft without starting the same activity again? The activity stacks and I need to press back for every update that has been made. Tried with an executor as well but doesn't seem to work.

Example: It's a game with questions. When I answer 5 questions, I get to question 6, I update any game field through the console, the activity starts again from question 1 with the new player count (if I have updated that field) and if I were to press back, I go back to the same activity at the 6th question.

I have tried all of these and only the if it is Java, it works. I haven't found any Kotlin variation that works.

Kotlin:

```
db.collection("games").document(gameID)
    .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
            if (e != null) {
                Log.w(tag, "Listen failed.", e)
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }
            if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
                val players = snapshot.data?.get("players") ?: 0
                if (players != 0) {
                    mPlayersLeft!!.text = "$players"
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(tag, "Current data: null")
            }    
     }
```

Java:

```
db.collection("games").document(gameID)
                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
                                        @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                        if (e != null) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
                            return;
                        }
                        if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
                            long players = (long) snapshot.getData().get("players");
                            mPlayersLeft.setText("" + players);
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Current data: null");
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Listener Java to Kotlin (via Android Studio translation):

```
db.collection("games").document(gameID)
        .addSnapshotListener(EventListener { snapshot, e ->
            if (e != null) {
                Log.w(tag, "Listen failed.", e)
                return@EventListener
            }
            if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
                val players = snapshot.data?.get("players") ?: 0
                if (players != 0) {
                    mPlayersLeft!!.text = "$players"
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(tag, "Current data: null")
            }    
     }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the activity starts again with the new data"?  Please be specific about what you're observing.

Comment: That's why I added an example after that.
In the lifecycle of the whole app, with each new Firestore field change, appears a new activity.
Example: Start Activity -> Questions Activity (field change starts another) - > Questions Activity etc.

Comment: None of the code you're showing here starts a new activity at all, so it's entirely unclear why that would happen based on what we can see. Kotlin isn't ever going to do something special to the activity that the equivalent Java wouldn't do.  Without more details, it's not really possible to say.

Comment: With some further debugging, I found that it is getStringExtra related, as when i use getStringExtra and set it for gameID, it does this, but when i use a static string in document("someStaticString"), everything works as I want.

Comment: There's really just not enough information here. I suggest editing the question with an MCVE that fully reproduces the issue, so that everyone can see all the moving parts.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass this(activity context) as first parameter.It will automatically handle acivity
life cycle. Example if you are calling this listener in onCreate() and passing this as a
first parameter then it will remove this listener in onDestroy() method of activity.

```
db.collection("games").document(gameID)
            .addSnapshotListener(this,new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
                                    @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
                        return;
                    }
                    if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
                        long players = (long) snapshot.getData().get("players");
                        mPlayersLeft.setText("" + players);
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Current data: null");
                    }
                }
            });
```